# How can I get the value of an ID into Ajax using $(this)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here I have 4 buttons. How can I get the value of the id for each button onto the end of `data: "id="` within the ajax part? Bare in mind, each id is unique as its using a numeric counter.

So for examples sake, if I clicked the third button then the `id` would equal `3`, if I clicked the second button, the `id` would 2... and so on.
Using `$("a").attr('id')` kind of works but it will grab the first `<a>` tag and stick with that value for which ever button you press. I also tried `$(this).attr('id')` but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

```
 <?php 
    $counter = 0;

        echo '
      <button><a class="test" id="'.++$counter.'">Test</a></button>
      <button><a id="'.++$counter.'">Test</a></button>
      <button><a id="'.++$counter.'">Test</a></button>
      <button><a id="'.++$counter.'">Test</a></button>
    ';

    ?>
      <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      $("button").click(function () 
      {

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
          data: "id="+ $("a").attr('id'),                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
          dataType: 'json',                //data format      
          success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
          {
            var id = data[0];              //get id
            var vname = data[1];           //get name
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // 3) Update html content
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
          }
        }); 
      }); 
      </script>
```

Comment: It would probably be better, semantically speaking, to remove the `<button>` tags and style the `<a>` so it *looks* like a button.

Comment: @Blazemonger There is no CSS yet, i left it default just for simplicity sake until inject it into my styled website.

Comment: Alternatively, just move the `id` attribute to the button and remove the `<a>` entirely. I see no good reason to nest them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("a").attr('id')` will retrieve all the anchor tags on the page and give you the first one's id.

In the context of your event handler function, `this` refers to the button element which was clicked.

To get the anchor tag *inside* the clicked button, you can use jQuery's [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('id');
```

This will find any child anchor tags and return the `id` attribute of the first one.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, this should work.

```
$(this).find('a').attr('id')
```

If you didn't want to traverse the DOM, however, you could just store the value in the button.

```
<button counterid="'.++$counter.'"><a class="test">Test</a></button>
<button counterid="'.++$counter.'"><a>Test</a></button>
<button counterid="'.++$counter.'"><a>Test</a></button>
<button counterid="'.++$counter.'"><a >Test</a></button>
```

Use the above for your HTML and then your JS would be:

```
$(this).attr('counterid')
```

I don't know php but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button").click(function () {
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   var id = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
   $.ajax({                                      
     url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
     data: "id="+id,                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
     dataType: 'json',                //data format      
     success: function(data) {
       var id = data[0];              //get id
       var vname = data[1];           //get name
       //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // 3) Update html content
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I find this answer also correct, so I accept this too.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("button").click(function (e) {

   var id = $(e.target).attr('id');

    $.ajax{ 
        //...make the ajax call as needed
    });
});
```

e is the event, e.target is the button element that triggered the click, you can then get its ID directly.

example http://jsfiddle.net/ZRA9K/

See http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: The `e` is an event object, not the element. Additionally, the ID we're trying to get is of the anchor tag inside the button, not the button itself.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the  `function (e)` part, I'm not sure as to why this was down voted as it'd work... But anyway, thank you for the suggestion.